# how to fetch data from webserver and store to our database through SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

i want to fetch data from web server and save it in my local database through sqllite.How is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch data from webserver using `JSON` and webservice and then parse the JSON Response string.

Then you may create insert statements from the data obtained and execute it to insert in your database using `executeNonQuery` method of SQLite.

Best option is to do all this on `appDidFinishLaunching` so that there would be initial delay but then whole app after that would not face any performance issues i.e. No delays

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

it depends on what kind of data you want to fetch. If you want to fetch XML from the webserver, you will get a nice list of xml parsers on this site: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Another nice option for fetching any kind of data from the webserver is curl. You can find static libraries on this page: http://code.google.com/p/ios-static-libraries/

Well, there's always the option to use the iOS native libraries, which are documented (with examples) in the iOS SDK.

Comment: i want to fetch JSON from web server and when once the data is fetched it should be simultanously saved to my local database

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using "raw" SQLite these days unless you have an exceptional reason to do so. Core Data is the way forward.

I'm not really sure what your question is; it's so broad. But, in general, you'd create an `NSURLConnection`, download the data, parse the data and store it in your database. Each stage is pretty well documented and there are lots of questions here on each stage.

If you use Core Data there are also some open source projects, such as [RestKit](http://restkit.org/), that might give you a good starting point.